# Parsing a table using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been struggling with Beautiful Soup and a web page. I want to parse a specific table from a web page, but I have had problems. My code is the following:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page    =     urllib2.urlopen("http://www.snet.gob.sv/googlemaps/workstation/main.php").read()
soup    = BeautifulSoup(page)


data = []
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "mytable" })
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values

print data
```

It works with another web pages, but not with this one. I get the following error:

```
table_body = table.find('tbody')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

It seems it does not find the tag "tbody", but I have checked and it is in the code. Another problem is that when it works (other web pages), a "u" is next to every item of the table. I have searched a lot and I cannot find the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It means that there _is_ no table with a class of mytable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RishavKundu. I have checked the web page and there is a table with the class "mytable".

Answer (score 1):

No, the error -

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

indicates that `table` is `None` , which means that the function -

```
soup.find("table", { "class" : "mytable" })
```

returned `None` , which indicates that the page does not have any table with property class having value - `mytable` .

You cannot just assume that html across different webpages would be exactly the same (otherwise all webpages would have looked exactly the same) .

I checked the url, and there really are no tables with that class, no table has any class at all in that particular page. You would need to decide which table you want to find and give the conditions accordingly.

Comment: It's weird. I used the inspector for that url and for the table I want to parse the class is "mytable". I don't know much of html and probably that is my problem. I will check it again. Thank you.

Comment: No, I'm stuck. I have used the inspector tool in chrome and what I get is "<table class="mytable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="font-size:8pt;font-family:Arial;"><tbody>" for the table I want. Thanks again for your help @Anand S Kumar.

Comment: I solved my problem. As you pointed out, there a no tables with that class when you look into the source code, though it appears when you use the inspector in firefox. I found a link to the table using the Network tab in the inspector in firefox.